# Go AppEngine won't start with goapp

Tags: google-app-engine, go, goland

Accordingly to [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/download)

I've downloaded "Cloud SDK" into my directory: `/Users/k/.google-cloud-sdk`

and "Original App Engine SDK" into my directory: `/Users/k/.go_appengine`

Now I try to run [my project](https://github.com/cn007b/monitoring)
which is located in dir: `/Users/k/web/kovpak/monitoring`

I've tried this:

```
export APP_YAML=/Users/k/web/kovpak/monitoring/src/go-app/.gae/app.yaml
export GOPATH=/Users/k/web/kovpak/monitoring
export APPENGINE_DEV_APPSERVER=/Users/k/.google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py
export GOROOT=/Users/k/.google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.9/
/Users/k/.google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.9/bin/goapp serve $APP_YAML
```

But it won't work, it prints:

> compile: version "1.9.4 (appengine-1.9.78)" does not match go tool version "go1.11"

Also I've tried this:

```
export APP_YAML=/Users/k/web/kovpak/monitoring/src/go-app/.gae/app.yaml
export GOPATH=/Users/k/web/kovpak/monitoring
export APPENGINE_DEV_APPSERVER=/Users/k/.go_appengine/dev_appserver.py
export GOROOT=/Users/k/.go_appengine/goroot-1.9
/Users/k/.go_appengine/goroot-1.9/bin/goapp serve $APP_YAML
```

And it also won't work.

But if I run this:

```
export APP_YAML=/Users/k/web/kovpak/monitoring/src/go-app/.gae/app.yaml
export GOPATH=/Users/k/web/kovpak/monitoring
/Users/k/.google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py $APP_YAML
```

All works!

Is it possible to run dev server with `goapp`? I need it for debugging from GoLand.

Comment: How are you trying to get this running in the IDE? None of those steps help reproduce the problem within the IDE. Are you using 2018.3 EAP.

Comment: @dlsniper When I hit "run" - GoLand runs: `goapp serve -host localhost -port 8080 -admin_port 8000 app.yaml` and fails. When I run same command without GoLand it also fails.

Comment: @dlsniper GoLand 2018.2.3; Build #GO-182.4505.32, built on September 20, 2018

Comment: @dlsniper Just downloaded IDE from https://jetbrains.com but it is `goland-2018.2.3.dmg` how to download 2018.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to run the go1.11 environment. I suspect you have:

```
runtime: go111
```

in your `app.yaml`.

Try changing it to

```
runtime: go
```